# How can I change language automatically with respect to user's location?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to change the language of my website. I defined two flags to change the language. I have two different tables for my native language and English. Here are the two functions shown below in my native language.

```
 [Route("BlogPost")]
        public ActionResult Blog(int Sayfa = 1)
        {
            ViewBag.Kimlik = db.Kimlik.SingleOrDefault();

            return View(db.Blog.Include("Kategori").OrderByDescending(x=>x.BlogId).ToPagedList(Sayfa,5));
        }
        [Route("BlogPost/{kategoriad}/{id:int}")]
        public ActionResult KategoriBlog(int id,int Sayfa=1)
        {
            ViewBag.Kimlik = db.Kimlik.SingleOrDefault();
            var b = db.Blog.Include("Kategori").OrderByDescending(x=>x.BlogId).Where(x => x.Kategori.KategoriId == id).ToPagedList(Sayfa,5);
            return View(b);
        }
```

When I click the flag, I want to define a string like "en". It changes the relavent page like `"/BlogPost/kategoriad/1"` to `"/en/BlogPost/kategoriad/1"` and `"www.websitename.com"` to `"websitename.com/en"`. How can I do that process to define a string when you change the language and call a relevant function. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12896687/177416 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928053/asp-net-mvc-switch-language-how-to-implement

Comment: @Alex Where do I define a code which detects browser language. How can I implement other process which I mentioned in my post?

Comment: @Alex Is it possible to explain each process step by step if you don't mind?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/ You may want to create a sample app and do this and then do it on your main project